# Mule: JUnit test is not working for file endpoint

Tags: file, testing, junit, mule

On running below flow under Mule server, Message.xml file located at C:\vikas\file location moved to C:\vikas\file\error location successfully.

```
<flow name="Demo" doc:name="Demo">

    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\vikas\file\"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\vikas\file\error"
        outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="ErrorQueue" />
</flow>
```

But, on running below JUnit test, 913d4c34-c754-11e2-8cfb-696bc9376bf8.dat file is created at C:/vikas/file location instead. Why Message.xml is not copied to C:\vikas\file\error location? How to fix it?

```
@Test
public void testFile() throws Exception {

    String fileInputPath = "file://C:/vikas/file";
    String payload = IOUtils.getResourceAsString(
            "Message.xml", this.getClass());
    client.dispatch(fileInputPath, payload, null);

    MuleMessage result = client.request(
            "file://C:/vikas/file/error", 5000);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you are reading the file successfully into `payload`? Is `vikas/file` in your classpath so that `getResourceAsString` will find it?

Comment: yes, it's reading the file successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it after adding Thread.sleep after client.dispatch() method.

```
@Test
public void testFile() throws Exception {

    String fileInputPath = "file://C:/vikas/file";
    String payload = IOUtils.getResourceAsString(
            "Message.xml", this.getClass());
    client.dispatch(fileInputPath, payload, null);

    Thread.sleep(685000);

    MuleMessage result = client.request(
            "file://C:/vikas/file/error", 5000);
}
```

Since dispatch is asynchronous method, Mule need some waiting time to complete the file move process.

Comment: FYI, I am not familiar with Mule but Camel (very similar) has built in test mechanisms to wait for async message completion (either via request vs send or using a Notifier). I would suggest looking into similar mechanism for Mule so you don't have that huge sleep.

Comment: Sleeping is a very fragile way of making asynchronous tests pass. Try using `send` instead of `dispatch`, that way Mule will block just the time required to write the file.

Comment: John, I didn't find similar approach in Mule on googling.        David, client.send can't work with File because exchange pattern "REQUEST_RESPONSE" for outbound endpoint file://dynamic is not supported.